# Batch Removal of multiple Unicode codes (ie. %20) from filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, unicode, filenames, batch-rename

I routinely work with file groups of 30,000-50,000 individual files, many of which have unicode codes included in the file name (ie %20, %5a, %5b, etc). To properly process these files, I need to replace these characters with an underscore.

I have a script I use to replace one of these codes at a time, but have to run several script to clean the lists and invariably miss some.

The script I use, with %20 as an example is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b ^| find "%20"') do (
set var01=%%I
set var02=!var01:%%5c=_!
call :ren
)
:ren
ren %var01% %var02%
```

This works fine for each code but I'd like to be able to find %** to find all of the codes and replace them at once. Is this something that can be done through a reasonably simple bat or would I need a more specialized tool?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: You would have to handle all possible hex-encoded values and while it could be done with some batch scripting, it's going to be fairly slow to check all 256 values.  I think you'll find a third party renaming tool which will handle that task and run quite swiftly.  @aacini might help you with a memory resident array that is quite efficient, if your filenames aren't too long (which would chew up the environment space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: remove variables starting $ 
For %%b IN ($) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR %%a IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f) DO (
 FOR %%b IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f) DO (
  SET "$%%a%%b=%%%%a%%b"
 )
)
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d^| find "%%"') do (
 SET "var1=%%I"
 FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%x IN ('set $') DO SET "var1=!var1:%%x=_!"
 IF "%%I" neq "!var1!" ECHO(REN "%%I" "!var1!"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should fix your problem.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Comment: That worked great, picked up all codes I came across in a test directory, replaced multiple codes in a single filename and worked faster than my single replace code.